# Error in Vector Autoregression because of NA values

Tags: r

I am trying to execute the following commands:

```
library(vars) # Load package
var.1 <- VAR(v1, 2, type = "none") # Estimate the model
```

for this variable:

```
> dput(v1)
c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 83065.8078463786, 80315.8839450438, 291505.602198517, 
221513.303866292, 279140.380651832, 298097.0639114, 272173.784046495, 
412897.18764903, 387304.736250378, 411286.048269894, 368148.919445238, 
422553.963363549, 387894.509272978, 379685.266347887, 323750.28443457, 
348857.195576222, 371270.579837624, 359926.267077774, 311822.695796726, 
368679.198734135)
```

How should I treat the NA values so that the VAR model gets executed correctly?

I don't want to change the NA values, I am just looking for a command such as `na.action=na.omit` for the lm regression

EDIT:

How about if I have the following data frame:

```
> var_matrix <- data.frame(v1,v2)
> dput(var_matrix)
structure(list(v1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, -519855.925178533, -247538.14528678, 
-603507.985623476, -873678.460926243, -581594.87915122, -528456.780577186, 
-391430.52605186, -474061.20379637, -508746.68301063, -551253.229288009, 
-745956.210848871, -395334.57220861, -660651.906124351, -650674.495666517, 
-554439.238524367, -603026.320962454, -636262.533420218, -627516.645815887, 
-563570.430739122, -669025.909101723), v2 = c(-0.0841196771292363, 
-0.0865340657541444, -0.0789115051898024, -0.0413000876182887, 
-0.0519876095584632, -0.0338526938134585, -0.017419320251823, 
-0.0227395626637981, 0.00747555221948315, 0.00490634907033316, 
0.0128726833736623, 0.00562952075313272, 0.000474645930122142, 
0.00414460086365942, -0.0236739434453794, 0.00536228308513542, 
-0.00400212632914532, -0.00956327795968659, 0.0121819821940745, 
-0.00875514068065508, 0.00407005673233352, 0.0158764252138643, 
0.0129726728437638, 0.015)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
```

where only the 1 variable has NAs?

Comment: You can use linear interpolation or some sort of smoothing to fill in the NAs but we need to know your actual use case. Also I think this question is better suited for CV site

Comment: @Sotos, I don't want to change the NA values, I am just looking for a command such as `na.action=na.omit` for the lm regression.

Comment: ok, then just `v1[!is.na(v1)]`?

Comment: I edited my post, how do I handle the case where only one variable has NAs in my dataframe? I want to get rid of these NAs and run the VAR on the non-missing values.

Comment: You dont have to differentiate between vectors with NAs and vectors without. You can just do something like `sapply(var_matrix, function(i) VAR(i[!is.na(i)]))`

Comment: This gives me the following error: `Error in VAR(i[!is.na(i)]) : 
  The matrix 'y' should contain at least two variables. For univariate analysis consider ar() and arima() in package stats.`

Comment: Oh wait..It needs a multivariate matrix? I am not familiar with that function so I don't know how it works...